# Problems with validity in type theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, type-theory, modal-logic

I'm twisting my brains over some simple formulas in intensional type theory.

**First**:

> If $\exists x \Box (x=^{\vee}j)$, s.t. $x$ is of type $<e>$ and refers to an entity $e$ and $j$ is of type $<s,e>$, refering to a function from possible worlds to intensional entities and $^{\vee}$ refers to the extension of $j$, I wonder is $\exists x \Box (x=^{\vee}j)$ valid?

I'm thinking on the hand that since extensions of an intensional expression are allowed to vary from one world to another on this theory, we cannot obtain a fixed constant $c$ of type $<e>$, being equivalent to the extension of $j$, for every possible world? But on the other hand, isn't it the case that constats aren't rigid on this theory, so that there are no grounds for saying that even a constant $c$ refers to a single entity e in every possible world?

**Second**:

> If $\exists x \Box(^{\wedge}x=j)$ where $x$ is of type $<e>$ and $j$ is of type $<s,e>$ and $^{\wedge}$ refers to the intension of $x$, is $\exists x \Box(^{\wedge}x=j)$ valid?

Here my primary concerns really revolve around the concept of intension. If $^{\wedge}x$ was substituted for $j$ of type $<s,e>$ let's say, would that make the equivalence valid? Would the intensions then be equivalent on every world? Is it saying something like $\Box(Mark Twain=Mark Twain)$ even if $\neg\Box(Mark Twain=Samuel Clemens)$ intensionally conceived? And could the former be granted for $\exists x \Box(^{\wedge}x=j)$? Mainly, is there a case where two intensional expressions are necessarily equivalent?

Comment: The problems are both from **Exercise 3**, page 128 of L.T.F. Gamut, [Logic, Language, and Meaning, Volume 2 : Intensional Logic and Logical Grammar](http://www.amazon.com/Logic-Language-Meaning-Intensional-Logical/dp/0226280888/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1418042624&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=Gamut+Logic+language+and+meaning+vol_2+Intensional+logic+and+logical+grammar+%281991%29) (1991). I think that you have to review the definitions of **5.4 Semantics**, page 121-on.

Comment: Thank's for your reply Mauro. Actually I did read the suggested pp's. Maybe there's something I don't get but my questions remain: Is c rigid (because of necessity), in which case necessity for the equivalence between c and j fails? Or is c not rigid, in which case it doesn't seem to pose a problem to validity, but is just a way of saying that the intensional expression j has some extension c at a world w, which could refer to different entities in different worlds? Intension on the other hand, doesn't vary over worlds right? Might that mean that intensions could be bound by necessity if j=j?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding : $∃x \square (x=^{\vee} j)$, you are right; in order to compute its truth-value, we have to "unwind" the semantical specifications of **Definition 4**, page 123.

We have that :

> $[[∃x \square (x=^\lor j)]]=1$ **iff** for some $d \in D, [[\square (x=^{\vee} j)]]_{M,w,g(x/d)} = 1$,

where $x$ is a variable of type $e$ and $j$ a constant of the same type.

This in turn holds **iff** for all $w' \in W : [[(x=^{\vee} j)]]_{M,w',g(x/d)} = 1$.

For the constant $j$, according to clause (ix), we have that $I(j) \in D^W$, i.e. $I(j)$ is a function mapping possible worlds into elements of $D$, and thus $I(j)(w)$ is an element of $D$, the reference of $j$ in $w$.

But it is not an individual constant $c$; thus its reference is not the same in every world.

We have that [page 57] :

> in every world $w, I_w(=) = \{ (d,d) | d \in D_w \}$;

thus, we cannot conclude that :

> for all $w' \in W : d = I(j)(w')$,

and so :

> > $∃x \square (x=^{\vee} j)$ is **not** valid.

---

With $∃x \square(^{\wedge} x=j)$, we have that $(^{\wedge} x=j)$ is a function from possible worlds into an open formula, i.e. an object of type $<s, <e,t>>$; accordingly, having chosen $d \in D$, we have that $[(^{\wedge} x=j)]_{M,g(x/d)}$ is a sentence, i.e. an object of type $<s,t>$.

Again we must have :

> $[[∃x \square(^{\wedge} x=j)]] = 1$ **iff**  for some $d \in D$ and for all $w' \in W : [[(^{\wedge} x=j)]]_{M,w',g(x/d)} = 1$.

Now we have to apply cluase (viii) : $[[(^{\wedge} x=j)]]_{M,w',g(x/d)}$ is that function $h \in \{ 0,1 \}^w$ such that for all $w' \in W : h(w') = 1$ **iff** $d = I(j)(w')$, and thus :

> > $∃x \square (^{\wedge} x=j)$ is valid.